# How to connect FreeSwitch to FreeSwitch?

Tags: voip, freeswitch

i have a problem with FreeSwitch. I tried for hours to connect a FreeSwitch server on my system with a FreeSwitch server on another system. However, what i want is to call with user "abc@myip" the user "123@buddysIp". What i tried is to add a new "list" item to the acl.conf.xml

```
<list name="buddy" default="deny">
      <node type="allow" cidr="hisip/32"/>
  </list>
```

also i tried to add an extension in the conf/dialplan/default directory

```
<include>
<extension name="outbound_calls">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(.*)$">
        <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/buddy/$1"/>
    </condition>
</extension>
```

and his gateway which is stored in conf/sip_profiles/buddy.xml and looks like this

```
<include>
<gateway name="buddy">
    <param name="realm" value="hisip"/>
    <param name="username" value="myuser"/>
    <param name="password" value="mypw"/>
</gateway>
```

I hope somebody can help me. Maybe i forgot something. 
We are in the same network. Please tell me if you need more informations, thanks.

Here are my call log:

```
 INVITE sip:666@myip SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:51155;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjyv0EW.k04poUhm7kdxHae5kheAypVEBc
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "me" <sip:1001@myip>;tag=Hd47q6ldQvMGLJO5RcMsO4AJQwWmRU28
   To: <sip:666@myip>
   Contact: "me" <sip:1001@myip:51155;ob>
   Call-ID: WW8ZDSQvHKuKTSjTJTX.hiefO6liAh7W
   CSeq: 24074 INVITE
   Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
   Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
   Session-Expires: 1800
   Min-SE: 90
   User-Agent: Telephone 1.1.4
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Length:   479

   v=0
   o=- 3621578544 3621578544 IN IP4 myip
   s=pjmedia
   b=AS:84
   t=0 0
   a=X-nat:0
   m=audio 4032 RTP/AVP 103 102 104 109 3 0 8 9 101
   c=IN IP4 myip
   b=TIAS:64000
   a=rtcp:4033 IN IP4 myip
   a=sendrecv
   a=rtpmap:103 speex/16000
   a=rtpmap:102 speex/8000
   a=rtpmap:104 speex/32000
   a=rtpmap:109 iLBC/8000
   a=fmtp:109 mode=30
   a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-15
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 382 bytes to udp/[myip]:51155 at 12:02:24.444389:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 100 Trying
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:51155;rport=51155;branch=z9hG4bKPjyv0EW.k04poUhm7kdxHae5kheAypVEBc
   From: "me" <sip:1001@myip>;tag=Hd47q6ldQvMGLJO5RcMsO4AJQwWmRU28
   To: <sip:666@myip>
   Call-ID: WW8ZDSQvHKuKTSjTJTX.hiefO6liAh7W
   CSeq: 24074 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.9+git~20140929T194948Z~ae069dcca7~64bit
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-10-06 12:02:24.435021 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1055 New Channel sofia/internal/1001@myip [2b0eddac-0ad5-41b3-a9f4-eebf1a81565e]
send 884 bytes to udp/[myip]:51155 at 12:02:24.450259:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:51155;rport=51155;branch=z9hG4bKPjyv0EW.k04poUhm7kdxHae5kheAypVEBc
   From: "me" <sip:1001@myip>;tag=Hd47q6ldQvMGLJO5RcMsO4AJQwWmRU28
   To: <sip:666@myip>;tag=9Q0rj5B37FS7H
   Call-ID: WW8ZDSQvHKuKTSjTJTX.hiefO6liAh7W
   CSeq: 24074 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.9+git~20140929T194948Z~ae069dcca7~64bit
   Accept: application/sdp
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="myip", nonce="72eb4930-85ce-4590-b2a2-b3420109fb4e", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 345 bytes from udp/[myip]:51155 at 12:02:24.450538:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ACK sip:666@myip SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:51155;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjyv0EW.k04poUhm7kdxHae5kheAypVEBc
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "me" <sip:1001@myip>;tag=Hd47q6ldQvMGLJO5RcMsO4AJQwWmRU28
   To: <sip:666@myip>;tag=9Q0rj5B37FS7H
   Call-ID: WW8ZDSQvHKuKTSjTJTX.hiefO6liAh7W
   CSeq: 24074 ACK
   Content-Length:  0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 1372 bytes from udp/[myip]:51155 at 12:02:24.450608:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:666@myip SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:51155;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjdQcDT3A-9MHF6CkHL-i9ocmvZjxVxGnD
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "me" <sip:1001@myip>;tag=Hd47q6ldQvMGLJO5RcMsO4AJQwWmRU28
   To: <sip:666@myip>
   Contact: "me" <sip:1001@myip:51155;ob>
   Call-ID: WW8ZDSQvHKuKTSjTJTX.hiefO6liAh7W
   CSeq: 24075 INVITE
   Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
   Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
   Session-Expires: 1800
   Min-SE: 90
   User-Agent: Telephone 1.1.4
   Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="1001", realm="myip", nonce="72eb4930-85ce-4590-b2a2-b3420109fb4e", uri="sip:666@myip", response="1220921ada500668b903722228634e1a", algorithm=MD5, cnonce="P1gGhwXHyrEHo1zMDrBEk3ryp1uKHbaK", qop=auth, nc=00000001
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Length:   479

   v=0
   o=- 3621578544 3621578544 IN IP4 myip
   s=pjmedia
   b=AS:84
   t=0 0
   a=X-nat:0
   m=audio 4032 RTP/AVP 103 102 104 109 3 0 8 9 101
   c=IN IP4 myip
   b=TIAS:64000
   a=rtcp:4033 IN IP4 myip
   a=sendrecv
   a=rtpmap:103 speex/16000
   a=rtpmap:102 speex/8000
   a=rtpmap:104 speex/32000
   a=rtpmap:109 iLBC/8000
   a=fmtp:109 mode=30
   a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-15
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 382 bytes to udp/[myip]:51155 at 12:02:24.450830:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 100 Trying
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:51155;rport=51155;branch=z9hG4bKPjdQcDT3A-9MHF6CkHL-i9ocmvZjxVxGnD
   From: "me" <sip:1001@myip>;tag=Hd47q6ldQvMGLJO5RcMsO4AJQwWmRU28
   To: <sip:666@myip>
   Call-ID: WW8ZDSQvHKuKTSjTJTX.hiefO6liAh7W
   CSeq: 24075 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.9+git~20140929T194948Z~ae069dcca7~64bit
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-10-06 12:02:24.484827 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:558 Processing me <1001>->666 in context default
2014-10-06 12:02:24.484827 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1628 WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING
2014-10-06 12:02:24.484827 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1628 Open /usr/local/freeswitch/conf/vars.xml and change the default_password.
2014-10-06 12:02:24.484827 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1628 Once changed type 'reloadxml' at the console.
2014-10-06 12:02:24.495177 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1628 WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING
2014-10-06 12:02:34.854471 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1055 New Channel sofia/external/666 [3bc1a418-d55d-4dab-863b-9742ec0ae187]
send 1113 bytes to udp/[buddyip]:5060 at 12:02:34.865554:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:666@buddyip SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:5080;rport;branch=z9hG4bK94rXNDv8U6KDg
   Max-Forwards: 69
   From: "Extension 1001" <sip:FreeSWITCH@buddyip>;tag=2N77KS1Ke6gpN
   To: <sip:666@buddyip>
   Call-ID: bc64e628-c7e2-1232-0e89-4d7ce0605bb2
   CSeq: 65958813 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:gw+amr@myip:5080;transport=udp;gw=amr>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.9+git~20140929T194948Z~ae069dcca7~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 292
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: "Extension 1001" <sip:2706446@buddyip>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1412565842 1412565843 IN IP4 myip
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 myip
   t=0 0
   m=audio 23912 RTP/AVP 3 0 8 9 101 13
   a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 363 bytes from udp/[buddyip]:5060 at 12:02:34.867644:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 100 Trying
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:5080;rport=5080;branch=z9hG4bK94rXNDv8U6KDg
   From: "Extension 1001" <sip:FreeSWITCH@buddyip>;tag=2N77KS1Ke6gpN
   To: <sip:666@buddyip>
   Call-ID: bc64e628-c7e2-1232-0e89-4d7ce0605bb2
   CSeq: 65958813 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14b+git~20141001T023048Z~a39db86863~64bit
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 865 bytes from udp/[buddyip]:5060 at 12:02:34.869949:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:5080;rport=5080;branch=z9hG4bK94rXNDv8U6KDg
   From: "Extension 1001" <sip:FreeSWITCH@buddyip>;tag=2N77KS1Ke6gpN
   To: <sip:666@buddyip>;tag=ytX68BX46p4Kp
   Call-ID: bc64e628-c7e2-1232-0e89-4d7ce0605bb2
   CSeq: 65958813 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14b+git~20141001T023048Z~a39db86863~64bit
   Accept: application/sdp
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="buddyip", nonce="56db4231-66c0-4603-bec6-7d6fb163a011", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 324 bytes to udp/[buddyip]:5060 at 12:02:34.870119:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ACK sip:666@buddyip SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:5080;rport;branch=z9hG4bK94rXNDv8U6KDg
   Max-Forwards: 69
   From: "Extension 1001" <sip:FreeSWITCH@buddyip>;tag=2N77KS1Ke6gpN
   To: <sip:666@buddyip>;tag=ytX68BX46p4Kp
   Call-ID: bc64e628-c7e2-1232-0e89-4d7ce0605bb2
   CSeq: 65958813 ACK
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 1389 bytes to udp/[buddyip]:5060 at 12:02:34.882192:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:666@buddyip SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:5080;rport;branch=z9hG4bKaejpQ8ccSFa0B
   Max-Forwards: 69
   From: "Extension 1001" <sip:FreeSWITCH@buddyip>;tag=2N77KS1Ke6gpN
   To: <sip:666@buddyip>
   Call-ID: bc64e628-c7e2-1232-0e89-4d7ce0605bb2
   CSeq: 65958814 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:gw+amr@myip:5080;transport=udp;gw=amr>
   Expires: 3600
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.9+git~20140929T194948Z~ae069dcca7~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, refer
   Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="FreeSWITCH", realm="buddyip", nonce="56db4231-66c0-4603-bec6-7d6fb163a011", cnonce="vGWirMfiEjKJDk184GBbsg", algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:666@buddyip", response="9455fd51fcf3ce264eb85a35fd311f23", qop=auth, nc=00000001
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 292
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: "Extension 1001" <sip:2706446@buddyip>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1412565842 1412565843 IN IP4 myip
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 myip
   t=0 0
   m=audio 23912 RTP/AVP 3 0 8 9 101 13
   a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 363 bytes from udp/[buddyip]:5060 at 12:02:34.883681:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 100 Trying
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:5080;rport=5080;branch=z9hG4bKaejpQ8ccSFa0B
   From: "Extension 1001" <sip:FreeSWITCH@buddyip>;tag=2N77KS1Ke6gpN
   To: <sip:666@buddyip>
   Call-ID: bc64e628-c7e2-1232-0e89-4d7ce0605bb2
   CSeq: 65958814 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14b+git~20141001T023048Z~a39db86863~64bit
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 724 bytes from udp/[buddyip]:5060 at 12:02:34.891400:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:5080;rport=5080;branch=z9hG4bKaejpQ8ccSFa0B
   From: "Extension 1001" <sip:FreeSWITCH@buddyip>;tag=2N77KS1Ke6gpN
   To: <sip:666@buddyip>;tag=Z3pZa7D83Zt6H
   Call-ID: bc64e628-c7e2-1232-0e89-4d7ce0605bb2
   CSeq: 65958814 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.14b+git~20141001T023048Z~a39db86863~64bit
   Accept: application/sdp
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 324 bytes to udp/[buddyip]:5060 at 12:02:34.891596:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ACK sip:666@buddyip SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:5080;rport;branch=z9hG4bKaejpQ8ccSFa0B
   Max-Forwards: 69
   From: "Extension 1001" <sip:FreeSWITCH@buddyip>;tag=2N77KS1Ke6gpN
   To: <sip:666@buddyip>;tag=Z3pZa7D83Zt6H
   Call-ID: bc64e628-c7e2-1232-0e89-4d7ce0605bb2
   CSeq: 65958814 ACK
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-10-06 12:02:34.884694 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7306 Hangup sofia/external/666 [CS_CONSUME_MEDIA] [CALL_REJECTED]
2014-10-06 12:02:34.899162 [INFO] mod_dptools.c:3234 Originate Failed.  Cause: CALL_REJECTED
2014-10-06 12:02:34.899162 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:4685 Hangup sofia/internal/1001@myip [CS_EXECUTE] [CALL_REJECTED]
send 888 bytes to udp/[myip]:51155 at 12:02:34.910248:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:51155;rport=51155;branch=z9hG4bKPjdQcDT3A-9MHF6CkHL-i9ocmvZjxVxGnD
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "me" <sip:1001@myip>;tag=Hd47q6ldQvMGLJO5RcMsO4AJQwWmRU28
   To: <sip:666@myip>;tag=a1SHm0v64rFtD
   Call-ID: WW8ZDSQvHKuKTSjTJTX.hiefO6liAh7W
   CSeq: 24075 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.9+git~20140929T194948Z~ae069dcca7~64bit
   Accept: application/sdp
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Reason: Q.850;cause=21;text="CALL_REJECTED"
   Content-Length: 0
   Remote-Party-ID: "666" <sip:666@myip>;party=calling;privacy=off;screen=no

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 345 bytes from udp/[myip]:51155 at 12:02:34.910602:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ACK sip:666@myip SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:51155;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjdQcDT3A-9MHF6CkHL-i9ocmvZjxVxGnD
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "me" <sip:1001@myip>;tag=Hd47q6ldQvMGLJO5RcMsO4AJQwWmRU28
   To: <sip:666@myip>;tag=a1SHm0v64rFtD
   Call-ID: WW8ZDSQvHKuKTSjTJTX.hiefO6liAh7W
   CSeq: 24075 ACK
   Content-Length:  0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-10-06 12:02:34.914727 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1633 Session 28 (sofia/external/666) Ended
2014-10-06 12:02:34.914727 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1637 Close Channel sofia/external/666 [CS_DESTROY]
2014-10-06 12:02:34.945164 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1633 Session 27 (sofia/internal/1001@myip) Ended
2014-10-06 12:02:34.945164 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1637 Close Channel sofia/internal/1001@myip [CS_DESTROY]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works know. I created a gateway in sip_profiles/external/mygateway.xml looks like

```
<include>
    <gateway name="buddygateway">
        <param name="proxy" value="buddyip"/>
        <param name="register" value="false"/>
        <param name="caller-id-in-from" value="true"/> <!--Most gateways seem to want this-->
    </gateway>
</include>
```

and created an outbound extension in dialplan/default/outbound_calls.xml looks like this:

```
<include>
    <extension name="outbound_calls">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^BUDDYPREFIX(\d*)$">
            <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/buddygateway/$1"/>
        </condition>
    </extension>
</include>
```

so every number i call now starts with BUDDYPREFIX calls the number on the remote server.

Thanks for the answers :) Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: i'd like to connect freeswitch to a third party voip server in the same network. will this work like that also?

Answer (score 0):

you can send the call to "external" SIP profile (port 5080), then it won't be authenticated. Then you need the dialplan rules in the public context to process such calls. Alternatively, you can create a new profile and attach it to a different UDP port, or even to a specific Ethernet port by explicitly specifying the bind IP address.

In the piece of log that you provided, it looks like the call is landed on port 51155. Is there a special SIP profile attached to that port? If so, probably you need to disable authentication on that profile.

But in general, you need to order a couple of hours of consultancy, so that a specialist explains you how things work. I can do that if needed too.

Comment: Something like this in dialplan/public.xml:
      <extension name="Calls from buddy">
          <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(*)$">
              <action application="transfer" data="$1 XML default"/>
          </condition>
      </extension>
Maybe i need a prefix like every call to 1234(number) must use the buddy gateway?